# How do I get PAM password authentication working?

Tags: linux, authentication, pam

I've been following [this](https://www.gulshansingh.com/posts/how-to-write-a-display-manager/) tutorial on writing my own display manager. I finished going through the PAM authentication code and after running the program, an authentication error is thrown. I've been doing some research about PAM and found out about these config modules in the /etc/pam.d directory. Do I need to create a module here? Or is there something else I need to do. The tutorial didn't say anything about this so I'm not sure what to do.